# How to Increment Value in Input field with AMP?

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to create a button in AMP that will increment the value in an input field. For example, what you would see in a quantity +- selector in an ecommerce product page.

I have tired looking at amp-bind, and amp-script, none of which seem to accomplish what I would consider so simple.

My AMP-HTML:

```
<button on="tap:AMP.setState({ value: value-1})">-</button>
<input name="qty" id="qty" type="number" min=1 [value]=1>
<button on="tap:AMP.setState({ value: value+1 })">+</button>
```

In normal javascript: it would be as simple as:

```
document.getElementById("qty").value++;
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current solution is really close.  The only thing that is missing is updating the `[value]` binding on the input to use the AMP state variable that gets modified when the button is clicked.  That will make the value dynamic based on the state variable.

For clarity I renamed the amp-bind variable from you example to be `currentValue`

```
<button on="tap:AMP.setState({ state: {currentValue: state.currentValue == 1 ? 1 : state.currentValue-1}})">-</button>
<input name="qty" id="qty" type="number" min=1 value=1 [value]="state.currentValue">
<button on="tap:AMP.setState({ state: {currentValue: state.currentValue+1 }})">+</button>
  
<amp-state id="state">
  <script type="application/json">
    {"currentValue": 1}
  </script>
</amp-state>
```

Here is a [full working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ezdw7ksp/1/) and the [amp-bind documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-bind/) is a great resource as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The major caveat to this solution is HTML uses the "value=" field to default the input value. I want the default to be 1 so users understand easily that is the quantity input and the most used option.

With your solution, the default input would be blank. I tried creating an amp-state but that doesn't seem to load until an event has activated. I would want this loaded on page load.

Right now, my only solution was to use a amp-script and have it embed as an iframe which seems like a painfully roundabout way to do this.

Comment: @Tenchu2525, I have updated the example to meet your needs.  When using amp-bind you can set the default attribute value by excluding the brackets around it.  So in this example we have the "value" attribute that sets the default value on load and "[value]" that reads from the amp-state variable when amp-bind gets evaluated when the user clicks a button.  I also created an amp-state to initialize the currentValue as 1.

Comment: @Tenchu2525, I have also updated the example so it does not allow the input to go below 1 when clicking the subtract button by adding a conditional statement to the AMP.setState() call.  Let me know if you need any further clarification on this!

AMP can be super frustrating when trying to figure out some of these things that would be basic in normal circumstances.  Once you get familiar with some of the common patterns used it gets easier.